# Bootstrap less compile parse error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, less

Using Drupal 7 bootstrap base theme.

https://drupal.org/node/1978010
Using method 1, did it step by step..

I am using local less compiler http://incident57.com/less/

When I compile I ./less/style.less

I get the following error.

ParseError: Syntax Error on line 643 in /application....[ThemeName]/bootstrap/less/mixins.less:643:25 642 padding-right:(@grid-gutter-width / 2);

I searched throughout drupal issue section, however only a hand full of people are having trouble.  I was wondering if someone here could shed some light since I am not getting much support from drupal community, see if I am missing something.

Thank you...

Comment: Latest Bootstrap sources require Less 1.6.x or higher. `Less.app` uses  Less 1.3.3 and can't compile Bootstrap 3.x.

Comment: ohhh, thank you!!!! ... which less compiler have 1.6 or higher?

Comment: Assuming you need it in OSX... hmm, `Brackets` (with either Less plugin) and `Crunch` are uptodate for sure. Maybe some [else](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less) (or [else](http://lesscss.org/usage/#editors-and-plugins)).

Comment: Now I am getting another error  NameError: varabile @blockquote-font-size undefined in type.less on line 233, column 14....
`
232 margin:0 0 @line-height-computed; 233 front-size:@blockquote-font-size; 234 border-left: 5px solid @blockquote` || so weird it seems like only I am getting this problem...  I went ahead and just added now it works now... Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there're just mixed files from different bootstrap versions (the `@blockquote-font-size` variable has been added in v3.1.1... and it is possible that the Drupal theme uses `variables.less` from v3.1.0).

Comment: Through drupal doc style.less has @import bootstrap.less which imports other .less files.  But  the weird thing is i keep getting variable undefined almost ever other .less file.

Comment: @seven-phases-max  thank you for looking in to this.  thank you for taking the time to check out drupal bootstrap.  I thought I was going crazy